# Permission issue: users can´t create content from certain computers

Tags: users

I am having a problem.

Users from a particular rol have permissions to create content.

When trying to create content from the office, we receive a message saying we have no permissions to do so. When connecting with the same user from other location, we receive no such message and we are able to create content.

Tried creating one new user with the same rol and the same problem.

Tried reseting roles and permissions and the same problem

Any ideas?

Comment: Can I just confirm, are you saying this is an existing problem that you want to solve, or a new feature you want to implement?

Comment: This is an existing big problem I want to solve

Comment: Would you mind adding a bit more info into the question (just click the 'edit' link)? For example, what specifically do you mean by "permission issues"? Are both users able to login at the same time? Does the problem happen when they try to save the _same_ piece of content on two different machines, or _any_ piece of content when they're logged in simultaneously? Do you see any error messages, if so exactly what do they say? A bit more context will help you get a much quicker answer